# Assigning empty string to integer yields zero

Tags: bash

I was surprised to discover the following behavior in Bash:

```
declare -i a=
declare -i b
declare c=
echo $a
echo :$b:
echo :$c:
```

Output:

> 0
>
> ::
>
> ::

Therefore assigning an empty string to an integer yields zero. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From section ARITHMETIC EVALUATION in `man bash`:

> The value of a variable is evaluated as an arithmetic expression when it  is  referenced,  or
>          when  a  variable  which  has been given the integer attribute using declare -i is assigned a value.  A null value evaluates to 0.

- `declare -i a=`

Variable `a` is given the integer attribute using declare -i and is assigned a null value, evaluating to `0`.

- `declare -i b`

No assignment, no arithmetic evaluation, `b` is still empty.

Note that `declare -i` is the only that presents that special behavior, as can be found in declare description under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS. So the last one,

- `declare c=`

maintains `c` empty instead of converting it to `0`.

Comment: Link https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html

Answer (score 1):

Note that the `declare` instruction does not reset existing value even if the `-i` flag is added, the existing value may become invalid.

The `-i` flag only affects value assignment.

```sh
declare -- a='hello'
typeset -p a
declare -- a="hello"
echo "$a"
hello
declare -i a # no reset of value, but adds the -i flag
typeset -p a
declare -i a="hello"
echo "$a" # a still contains "hello" despite the -i flag
hello
a='world' # but a new value assignment will be filtered by the -i flag
typeset -p a
declare -i a="0"
echo "$a"
0
```

The behavior of the array flag `-a` differs quite a bit:

```sh
unset a
a=
typeset -p a # a contains an empty string
declare -- a=""
declare -a a # the -a flag converts the existing value to an entry even if the string is empty
typeset -p a
declare -a a=([0]="")
```

To sum it up:
The `-i` flag only converts the value during assignment.
The `-a` flag converts the value during declaration as well.